# How to force a flash video to reread a text file online

Tags: html, actionscript-3

Sorry i was not sure how to summarize the question. Ok I have a .swf on a website that reads text from a .txt file uploaded to the same directory. The problem is once the swf has been loaded once the cookies have to be cleared for it to reread the .txt file. So my question is how would i force it to check the .txt file everytime?

Sorry if this is a dumb question I am not even sure if it needs to be in the AS or html/java.
I am more of a offline programmer this is my first time working with anything online.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to append something unique to the txt files URL, like so:

> my_text_file.txt#543

ofcourse, that does not look very unique. The appended string does not have to be unique across multiple uses, or even between sessions. Your main goal is to reload the txt file if some time has passed. Therefore the best/easiest way I can think of, is to append the current date string (in milliseconds).

```
var myTextFileURL:String = 'my_text_file.txt';
myTextFileURL += '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
```

Then use that url string to load your txt file.